# Using JQuery, how can I make a field editable, but user can't type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field that has a date control popup when the user clicks in it.  The problem is, that the user can also enter invalid dates.

Is there a way using Javascript to leave the field editable, but prevent the user from typing any numbers?

Comment: In what way is it 'editable,' if the user can't type into it?

Comment: its not directly editable but the value can change. Does not make it very accessible though

Comment: Didn't want it to look disabled, just prevent typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind keydown handler to that text field and return false number was pressed:

```
$('#field_id').keydown(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 59)
    return false;
  return true;
});
```

if you want to also prevent ctrl-v and context menu(to be able to paste from it) use

```
$('#field_id').keydown(function(event){
  var k = event.keyCode;
  if((k > 47 && k < 59) || (k == '86' && event.ctrlKey))
    return false;
  return true;
}).bind('contextmenu',function(e){
  return false;
});
```

for linux you should also consider preventing middle click paste :)

Comment: Thanks petho, since I didn't have control over the original HTML generation, this seemed the simplest way to acheive the same result.

Comment: Does this prevent paste via keyboard or right mouse click or drag/drop?  I don't think it does.

Comment: no, it doesn't prevent paste via keyboard nor mouse. You would have to hack more to prevent that. Keyboard paste should be easy (just a few things added to if statement), mouse would need hacking mousedown event handling and preventing context menu to pop-up, not sure if you can do this in all relevant browsers

Comment: added also keyboard paste + context menu paste prevention. Of course nothing is perfect, it is still hackable if you use ctrl-v for paste or if you use middle click for paste, or have browser that is not supported by jquery contextmenu event :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a readonly field:

`<input type="text" readonly="readonly" /`>

It can still be modified with javascript and you can still intercept click events, but the user cannot type in it or copy/paste in it or drag/drop to it.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9SsZq/

Options that try to intercept keystrokes may not prevent everything (like drag/drop).  It makes more sense to use the built-in readonly capabilities.

Comment: I've used this solution with the jQuery UI datepicker.  It works.  +1

Comment: +1 for showing me a attr i have never seen before, does this work in IE7 & 8 to?

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, sounds good.  In this case I don't have access to the original rendering.  I could add the readonly attr via JQuery, a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** ignore my answer and use the [widely supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) `readonly` attribute @jfriend00 mentions.

---

**Original:**

You could try to prevent the default action for `keydown`, but users will still be able to paste (or find other "clever" ways to get unwanted data into it).

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
.change(function() {
  // Put default value back in
  // NOTE: this only fires when focus is lost
});
```

A better option would probably be to use the `disabled` property and use CSS to make it [look right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232188/default-textbox-border-style-and-width).

```
<input type="text" class="looks-enabled" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: you should check the onChange to because the user could copy paste a date, without using the keyboard.

Comment: @meo, you're right. My original test used that but I was missing the fact that `onchange` only fires when focus is lost -- I thought that it wasn't firing at all and thus left it out of the original post. Updated.