# gwt datebox not getting the default Css

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, datebox

I have created a Datebox in Uibinder .

```
       <d:DateBox ui:field="completedDate"></d:DateBox>
```

and have not define any css for this

I am getting a white background datebox ,without any format, in Chrome 
in firefox its fine ..

I have tried all of these one by one and also all together , but no luck in Chrome .

```
        <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/> 
        <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>  
        <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
```

Any idea

or if someone can give me the default css which i can add inside

```
    .gwt-DateBox{

       }
```

thanks

Comment: DateBox has no unique styles in GWT. It's just a textbox, and it looks like a textbox in every browser. What do you mean when you say it looks fine in Firefox but not in Chrome? Can you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you want the firefox-look in chrome?

I would recommend defining a style that suits your needs and set it for the DateBox, so you have a unique look for various browsers.

Maybe take a look at this question for the textbox:
[Default textbox border-style and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232188/default-textbox-border-style-and-width)