# how to remove css from the text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, stylesheet

The question might sound dumb... but I have a code that is applying a css on a text box. now I want it to be set as default again on another condition.

Or to be precise I want to sent my textbox to its default style.

Searching on the internet and stackoverflow I have fount these answers -

[Default textbox border-style and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232188/default-textbox-border-style-and-width)

Any help?

EDIT :

```
    if (condition)
        {
            txtLastName.CssClass="ControlBackground_Yellow"; 
        }
    else
        {               
            txtLastName.CssClass="ControlBackground_White"; 
        }
```

css is --

```
ControlBackground_Yellow    
{
    background-color:#FFFF00;
}

ControlBackground_White     
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

PS:**sorry not allowed to use jQuery**

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?  What's the code that's applying the CSS?  You can probably do this just by removing the relevant class.

Comment: look here if I understand you correctly you are wanting to set the style this can be done in code as well look here [WebControl.CssClass Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx)

Comment: adited the question to elaborate.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this server side? Surely, surely, surely, the logic controlling your css belongs in your javascript on the frontend?

Comment: no the code written is on my class file.

Comment: @akhil If the code is in cs file, it's not good at all. Styling/CSS etc is markup thing and should be applied in HTML/CSS/JS etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to remove css class from your control based on certain condition:

```
 var $arrow = jQuery('<div class="arrow"></div>');

 $arrow.removeClass();
```

You can again add class:

```
 $arrow.addClass('className');
```

Comment: sorry not allowed to use jQuery

Comment: Your answer is also correct as I have seen in various websites but the problem is that I just can't use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation you can either:

Use jQuery to remove/addClasses on your textbox:

```
  $('input[type=text].yourClass#yourId)).removeClass('class_to_remove');
  $('input[type=text].yourClass#yourId)).removeClass('class_to_add');
```

Or use jQuery to directly set css values:

```
  $('input[type=text].yourClass#yourId)).css('display', 'block');
  $('input[type=text].yourClass#yourId)).css('border-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed this line

```
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

from my css.

```
    ControlBackground_Yellow    
{
    background-color:#FFFF00;
}

ControlBackground_White     
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

thanks guys for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this line from code behind as well:

```
textBox.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

The word "class" points to the current class applied to the textBox, does not need to replace this text. Hope it helps.